# Greeks of a swaption using Brigo

Tags: swaption

I struggeling with calculating the delta of a swaption. In the interest rate case I usually mess around with the multiple cash flows over time so that the discounting is more complex than in the equity case.

Let me first introduce some notation. We denote with $D(0,T)$ the discounting factor with maturity $T$, $P(0,T)$ the price of a zero coupon bond with maturity $T$ and let $Q$ denote the risk neutral measure.

By simple risk neutral valuation we know:

$$D(0,0)V_0 = V_0 = E_Q[V_TD(0,T)|\mathcal{F}_t]$$

No we are interested in a swaption, where we expiry of the option is at $T_\alpha$ and the underlying swap has a tenor $T_\beta$. The discounted value of the swpation can be writen as

$$D(t,T_\alpha)(S_{\alpha,\beta}(T_\alpha)-K)^+\sum_{i=\alpha + 1}^\beta\tau_iP(T_\alpha,T_i)$$

where $\tau_i$ is the daycount convention between $T_{i-1}$ and $T_i$.

Now regarding valution using the above two equations:

$$ V_0 = E_Q[D(0,T_\alpha)(S_{\alpha,\beta}(T_\alpha)-K)^+\sum_{i=\alpha + 1}^\beta\tau_iP(T_\alpha,T_i)|\mathcal{F}_0]$$

using a smart change of numeraire, the swap measuer $S$, i.e. the numeraire introduced by $\sum_{i=\alpha + 1}^\beta\tau_iP(t,T_i)$ yield

$$ V_0 = E_Q[D(0,T_\alpha)(S_{\alpha,\beta}(T_\alpha)-K)^+\sum_{i=\alpha + 1}^\beta\tau_iP(T_\alpha,T_i)|\mathcal{F}_0]=\sum_{i=\alpha + 1}^\beta\tau_iP(0,T_i)E_S[(S_{\alpha,\beta}(T_{\alpha})-K)^+|\mathcal{F}_0]$$

We know that under the measure $S$, the forward swap rate $S_{\alpha,\beta}(t)$ is a martingale. For the price we could now simple apply Black formula, if we assume that the forward swap rate is normally distributed.

Now my question, if I would apply the normal calculation for the delta I would get $\sum_{i=\alpha + 1}^\beta\tau_iP(0,T_i) N(d_1)$, where $d_1$ is the expression from Black 76 formula. However this term $\sum_{i=\alpha + 1}^\beta\tau_iP(0,T_i)$ annoys me. I get completely wrong results. If I used just $N(d_1)$ I would get reasonable result. So my question, is the delta given by $N(d_1)$ for a swaption as well? If so, where is my mistake?

For simplicity I add an example with concrete numbers.

**example**
We take a swaption with expiry $5$ years and underlying tenor of $5$ years.
$S_{\alpha,\beta}(0) = 0.0271$, $\sigma = 0.34$, $r = 0.011$, $T=5$, $K = 0.028$ and annuity $A=4.92$. Using Black 76 we should get for $\Delta$:

$$\Delta = A\cdot N(d_1),$$ where

$$d_1 = \frac{\log{\frac{S_{\alpha,\beta}(0)}{K}}+\frac{\sigma^2\cdot T}{2}}{\sigma\cdot\sqrt{T}}$$

Here I get the values $N(d_1) = 0.332296$ and $\Delta = 1.634896$, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean with wrong results? I guess your Delta is ok, as the Black76 call is linear in the forward swap rate as seen at time t

Comment: When you say Bringo, do you mean D. Brigo, the author and his famous textbook?

Comment: @GabrielePompa Hi, I added an example. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @AlexC Yes, I mean D.Brigo and his famous text book

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not understand what's the problem with that Delta. Is it because it's greater than one that disturbs you?

Comment: @GabrielePompa exactly, In equities you have a bound of the delta. Why can it exceed 1?

Comment: not sure, intuitively: in equity the underlying $S_t$ is a tradable asset, instead the underying of the swaption - the forward swap rate $S_{\alpha \beta}(0)$ - is not tradable _per se_, what you can do is enter in the swap. So, to compare the two deltas you should compare the variation of the call price on the variation of the tradable underlying. This is $\Delta/1 = N(d_1)$ in the case of equity and $\Delta_{PS}/BPV_{payer\mbox{ }swap}=\frac{A N(d_1)}{A} = N(d_1)$ since an increase of the swap rate of 1bp leads to a payer swap worth $A \$ $ more

Comment: Hi, _tradable_ underlying (the swap) was just to distinguish it from the _functional_ underlying (the forward swap rate). Well, Delta is the quantity that multiplied by the "Delta" of the underlying (variation in its price wrt the variation in the functional underlying of the call) makes the {call; trad. underl.} portfolio Delta neutral. In the case of swaption, you should enter in a swap with nominal $ N(d_1) $ times the nominal of the swap underlying the swaption. Someone could clarify me as well with a more formal argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the swap rate is not tradable, the delta hedge ratio with respect to the spot swap rate is not really useful. However, note that
\begin{align*}
V_0 &= \sum_{i=\alpha+1}^{\beta}\tau_i P(0, T_i)\big[S_{\alpha, \beta}(0)N(d_1) - k N(d_2) \big]\\
&= \sum_{i=\alpha+1}^{\beta}\tau_i P(0, T_i) S_{\alpha, \beta}(0)N(d_1) - N(d_2) k \sum_{i=\alpha+1}^{\beta}\tau_i P(0, T_i)\\
&= \Big[P(0, T_{\alpha}) -  P(0, T_{\beta})\Big]N(d_1) - N(d_2) k \sum_{i=\alpha+1}^{\beta}\tau_i P(0, T_i)\\
&= \bigg[P(0, T_{\alpha}) -  P(0, T_{\beta})- k \sum_{i=\alpha+1}^{\beta}\tau_i P(0, T_i)\bigg]N(d_1) \\
& \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad + \Big[N(d_1)- N(d_2)\Big] k \sum_{i=\alpha+1}^{\beta}\tau_i P(0, T_i).
\end{align*}
Here,
\begin{align*}
A_{\alpha, \beta} &\triangleq P(0, T_{\alpha}) -  P(0, T_{\beta}) - k \sum_{i=\alpha+1}^{\beta}\tau_i P(0, T_i)\\
&= \sum_{i=\alpha+1}^{\beta}\tau_i P(0, T_i)\big[S_{\alpha, \beta}(0) -k \big]
\end{align*}
is the value of the underlying swap, and
\begin{align*}
k \sum_{i=\alpha+1}^{\beta}\tau_i P(0, T_i)
\end{align*}
is the value of a portfolio of zero-coupon bonds. We define the delta hedge ratio of the swaption to the derivative of the swaption value with respect to the swap value $A_{\alpha, \beta}$. Note that
\begin{align*}
S_{\alpha, \beta}(0) = \frac{A_{\alpha, \beta}}{\sum_{i=\alpha+1}^{\beta}\tau_i P(0, T_i)} + k.
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial V_0}{\partial A_{\alpha, \beta}} &= \frac{\partial V_0}{\partial S_{\alpha, \beta}(0)} \frac{\partial S_{\alpha, \beta}(0)} {\partial A_{\alpha, \beta}}\\
&= N(d_1),
\end{align*}
which is, for hedging purpose, the quantity of the underlying swap to buy.

See alos the discussion in http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.28.7064&rep=rep1&type=pdf.

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation and the link. What would be interesting to know why exactly $A_{\alpha,\beta}$ is considered to measure the change. Sure it is a tradable asset, but the connection to the swaption / swap is not fully clear yet (to me). For example, a swap can also be decomposed into FRA's contracts which are tradable asset. I'm new to these things and still lacking of the intuition. Thanks for your help and the pdf.

Comment: @user8: I made some changes, where I changed $A_{\alpha, \beta}$ to the value of the underlying swap. This is now comparable to equity options. That is, the delta hedge ratio is the derivative with respect to the underlying asset.

Comment: Many thanks Gordon! Its much clearer now.

Comment: thanks gordon. I really like the paper! Maybe one last question. In the equity case, i.e. call on a future $F$: $C=\beta(t)E_Q[\frac{1}{\beta(T)}(F-K)^+|\mathcal{F}_t]$. Using Black 76 we see that the forward delta, $\frac{dC}{dF} = \frac{1}{\beta(t)}N(d_1)$. $F$ is the underlying and can be traded. Why do we have there a discounting factor? It seems to me, one can't really make a linke between equity and the FI case.

Comment: @user8: Forward delta and spot delta are different. You can also check this in the FX world. All depending on how we define the delta. In FI world, we usually do not define the delta, instead, we define the rho with respect to the interest rate curve.

Comment: maybe my last comment was not that clear. A swaption is like a call on a future, isn't it? That's the reason why uses the Black 76 formula for quoting. Therefore, in the equity world (call on a future) your delta is $\beta N(d_1)$ since your underlying is tradable. You have the discount factor in front. However, taking in FI the derivative wrt to the underlying $A_{\alpha,\beta}$ cancels the discount (annuity) part, which seems counter intuitive. That was my question in the last comment

Comment: I would treat the swaption as an equity option with the swap as the underlier. The Black's 76 formula does not mean it should be the same as the futures option; it was derived by Black in 1976 with a lot of approximations, and is in a completely different way from that of futures options. Historically, he derived this formula long before the introduction of the swap measure. In summary, the name of the formula refers to the history, but no relation to futures options. If you treat a swaption as an option on a swap with zero strike, it will be exactly like an equity option.

Comment: In addition, there is no particular restriction on how should one define the hedge ratio. For example, people also call the derivative with respect to a zero rate as zero delta, while the derivatives with respect to the interest rates (e.g., money market rates, swap rates etc.) employed for the swap curve construction as the coupon deltas.

Comment: Very interesting. I thought it was by purpose to use the black 76 because of future payoffs like in a future case. About the different definition: thats maybe the most confusing part in FI. There are alot of slightly different definition of similar things, eg duration etc. That makes it at the beginning much more confusing than the equity casr

Comment: That is also the interesting part in FI. Basically, for interest rate derivatives, the math appears more elegant.

Comment: I will reward the bounty tm. On the app there isnt a button to reward it. Many thanks for your patience and explanations. This was very helpful.