# When calculating swaption greeks, would annuity need to be considered?

Tags: greeks, swaption

we all know that swaption price = annuity * black price.
The question is that when calculating risks, should we treat annuity as a constant. i.e. is it correct that swaption delta = annuity * black delta?

Or we need to take annuity into account? In theory, swap rate changes would impact annuity. In particular, for theta, shorten time would certainly change the value of annuity, wouldn't it? in this case, swaption delta = annuity * black theta would not hold.

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/76876/how-is-this-greek-calculation-meaningful?noredirect=1&lq=1 answers this question

Comment: Would you explain how "black delta" being came?

Comment: delta coming out of black-76  model